# How to store online JSON API in SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, api, sqlite

So I'm trying to develop this app which stores weather details into a sqlite database with Android Studio. I'm currently watching a tutorial on how to store json data to an SQLite Database, but this is for reading from a JSON file.

```
private String readJsonDataFromFile() throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        String jsonDataString = null;
        inputStream = mResources.openRawResource(R.raw.menu_item);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        while ((jsonDataString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(jsonDataString);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    return new String(builder);
}
}
```

For example he is reading in a JSON file called menu_item. How would I implement the code above to work if I wanted to use it to store data from a MetaWeather api, for ex: https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=paris

Answer (score 0):

You could use a http library for retrieving responses from api calls I recommend `OkHttp`. https://square.github.io/okhttp/

You will receive a response body from the API call as a string and everything else should be the same as your posted code after you have the string.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    return response.body().string();
  }
}
//HERE
run("https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=paris")
```